# How to verify the mail account is signed in or not programmatically before sending mail?

Tags: android, email

In my application i wrote a code to send mail.This code showing me compose mail and iam able to send mail from my account,eventhough that account is not signed in.But that mail 
is not sent to receiver whithout signing in.

I thought that compose screen will shows you from already signed in mail account only.But if once configured mail account ,from that one without verifying signed in or not it is showing compose screen.So i want to very before showing compose screen the email account is signed in or not if now want to show sign in screen.

How to verify the account is signed in or not programmatically.

code snippet:

```
Intent lIntent = new Intent();
        lIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        lIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mailSubject);
        lIntent.setType("text/plain");
        lIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
            ""
        });
        // lIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{""});
        lIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        lIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mailBody);
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(lIntent, "Send Email"));

   } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            //showing email not configured alert
        }
```